# ngModel value not updating

Tags: angular, angular6

I have the below code written , on the paste event I want to change the ngModel value

```
<input [ngModel]="field[index].value" (paste)="field[index].value=myFunction($event)"/>
```

myFunction in component is as below:

```
   myFunction(event):string
    {
     //Some String processing
     return "pasted_processed_Value";
    }
```

However, I am able to log the processed string in myFunction method but the value returned from myFunction is not updated in ngModel

Comment: Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: no i don't see any errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input [ngModel]="hello" (paste)="myFunction($event)"/>

myFunction(event):string
{
  //Some String processing
  this.hello = "pasted_processed_Value";
}
```

EDIT:

```
   (paste)="myFunction($event, field[index])"

   myFunction(event, field):string
    {
     //Some String processing
     field.value = "pasted_processed_Value";
    }
```

Comment: Your ansswer was almost correct just instead of [ngModel] i had to do [(ngModel)] and instead of myFunction($event, field[index]) i had to do this myFunction($event, field)

Answer (score 0):

Make it a two-way binding instead -> `[(ngModel)]`

`<input [(ngModel)]="field[index].value" (paste)="field[index].value=myFunction($event)"/>`